# Why Pin::new_unchecked(&self) worked but not Pin::new_unchecked(&self).as_ref()?

Tags: rust, rust-pin

I was writing a `StackBox` that references a variable allocated on a memory-mapped stack and implemented `Drop` trait so that `StackBox` can be used as a reference.

Since I can guarantee that if `StackBox` is ever created by my code, then the memory-mapped stack must not be modified, I decided to add `pin` method that returns `Pin<&T>`.

However I found it weird that `Pin::new_unchecked(&self)` worked but `Pin::new_unchecked(&self).as_ref()` doesn't work.

Here's the full code of `StackBox`:

```rust
pub struct StackBox<'a, T> {                      
    ptr: *mut T,                                  
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a T>,                  
}                                                 
impl<'a, T> StackBox<'a, T> {                     
    fn new(ptr: *mut T) -> StackBox<'a, T> {      
        StackBox {                                
            ptr,                                  
            phantom: PhantomData                  
        }                                         
    }                                             
    /// Why does this compile?
    /// Pin::new_unchecked(&self).as_ref() doesn't work here
    pub fn pin(&self) -> Pin<&T> {                
        unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&self) }      
    }                                             
}                                                 
impl<'a, T> Drop for StackBox<'a, T> {            
    fn drop(&mut self) {                          
        unsafe {                                  
            self.ptr.drop_in_place();             
        }                                         
    }                                             
}                                                 
impl<'a, T> Deref for StackBox<'a, T> {           
    type Target = T;                              
                                                  
    fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {            
        unsafe { & *self.ptr }                    
    }                                             
}                                                 
impl<'a, T> DerefMut for StackBox<'a, T> {        
    fn deref_mut(&mut self) -> &mut Self::Target {
        unsafe { &mut *self.ptr }                 
    }                                             
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are writing `Pin::new_unchecked(&self)` you probably mean `Pin::new_unchecked(self)` because `self` is already a reference, but the analysis is basically the same:

```
    pub fn pin(&self) -> Pin<&T> {
        unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(self) }
    }
```

You are probably thinking that you are creating a `Pin<&StackBox<T>>` and then it magically gets converted into a `Pin<&T>`.

But that is not really what it is happening. It is actually deducing the type of the function call from the return type, so you are calling `Pin::<&T>::new_unchecked()` and it is the `self` that is converted into a `&T` in this call, by using the `deref()` impl from below. It is as if:

```
    pub fn pin(&self) -> Pin<&T> {                
        unsafe { Pin::<&T>::new_unchecked(self.deref()) }
    }
```

This can be written more obviously as:

```
    pub fn pin(&self) -> Pin<&T> {                
        unsafe { Pin::new_unchecked(&*self.ptr) }
    }
```

As to why the version with `as_ref()` does not work, this is because your `self` is a `&StackBox<T>`, not a `StackBox<T>`. `as_ref()` is useful to remove a smart-pointer layer, so it can convert a `Pin<Box<T>>` into a `Pin<&T>`, for example. But if you start with a `Pin<&Box<T>>` (that doesn't make too much sense), there is no conversion to be done.